# What library to install for Wonderpush in react native?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, wonderpush

Hi what are the libraries to install in order to use the Wonderpush notifications in react-native ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

How about this? https://github.com/wonderpush/react-native-wonderpush 

 It's looks like working on React Native

Comment: Thanks for your response ! I've tried this lib but when I want to `npm install` it says that `'react-native-wonderpush@latest' is not in the npm registry.`

Comment: You can try `npm install "https://github.com/wonderpush/react-native-wonderpush"`